# How to change WSDL and add input variables in Proxy Service?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I created proxy service in WSO EI 6.4.0, which send email. In the flow I use properties: AttachmentFile, transport.mail.bodyWhenAttached, senderAddress and Subject. How to create custom wsdl with input parameters sender_address, subject, mail_text, attachment_file. or what other solution can you use?
I want to call this proxy server via API and send the parameters.

```
<inSequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property name="transport.mail.Format" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="Attachment"/>
    <property name="AttachmentFile" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="attachment.csv"/>
    <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/html"/>
    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/html"/>
    <property expression="Some body text" name="transport.mail.bodyWhenAttached"
        scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
    <property name="senderAddress" scope="default" type="STRING" value="test@test.com"/>
    <property name="Subject" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="WSO Email Test"/>
    <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
    <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
    <log level="full"/>
    <header
        expression="fn:concat('mailto:', get-property('senderAddress'))"
        name="To" scope="default"/>
    <call>
        <endpoint>
            <default/>
        </endpoint>
    </call>
</inSequence>
```

Comment: The one which you have created is a sequence , you need to create a proxy service , if you are not aware of wsdl file then use custom proxy and in the in sequence you can refer the sequence which you have created.Once the proxy is created it will generate wsdl by default.

Comment: @amg_amit thanks. I'm new in wso. I'll be grateful, if you explain some example with xml

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Save the below file with the name `sendEmailProxy.xml` under the location

> //repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/proxy-services

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
               name="sendEmailProxy"
               startOnLoad="true"
               statistics="disable"
               trace="disable"
               transports="http,https">
           <target>
              <inSequence>
                 <property name="transport.mail.Format"
                           scope="axis2"
                           type="STRING"
                           value="Attachment"/>
                 <property name="AttachmentFile"
                           scope="axis2"
                           type="STRING"
                           value="attachment.csv"/>
                 <property name="ContentType"
                           scope="axis2"
                           type="STRING"
                           value="text/html"/>
                 <property name="messageType"
                           scope="axis2"
                           type="STRING"
                           value="text/html"/>
                 <property name="senderAddress"
                           scope="default"
                           type="STRING"
                           value="test@test.com"/>
                 <property name="Subject"
                           scope="transport"
                           type="STRING"
                           value="WSO Email Test"/>
                 <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
                 <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED"
                           scope="axis2"
                           type="STRING"
                           value="true"/>
                 <log level="full"/>
                 <header expression="fn:concat('mailto:', get-property('senderAddress'))"
                         name="To"
                         scope="default"/>
                 <call>
                    <endpoint>
                       <default/>
                    </endpoint>
                 </call>
                 <respond/>
              </inSequence>
           </target>
<parameter name="useOriginalwsdl">true</parameter>
           <description/>
        </proxy>
```

Once it is saved start wso2 EI/ESB instance , log into the instance, then click on service which is on left hand side of screen below `services` you wil find the proxy, You will have two options `wsdl1.1 wsdl2.0` click on which ever you prefer , this would provide the wsdl file for you proxy

If you are already having a custom wsdl and want wso2 to pick up that wsdl then you need to add the below parameter

> `<parameter name="useOriginalwsdl">true</parameter>`

This would accept your custom wsdl and wso2 will not generate it's own wsdl